Help with proof for particular + homogenous solution of a linear system
I'm trying to understand the a proof for the following Lemma, from a section of the Linear Algebra wikibook on Nonhomogeneous Systems. The wikibook is based on Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon.

Lemma 3.8
For a linear system, where $\vec p$ is any particular solution, the solution set equals this set.
$$
\{\vec{p}+\vec{h} \,\big|\, \vec{h}\text{ satisfies the associated homogeneous system}\}
$$
Corollary 3.11
Solution sets of linear systems are either empty, have one element, or have infinitely many elements.
Proof
We've seen examples of all three happening so we need only prove that those are the only possibilities.
First, notice a homogeneous system with at least one $non-\vec{0}$
solution $\vec{v}$ has infinitely many solutions because the set of
multiples $s\vec{v}$ is infinite— if $s\neq 1$ then
$s\vec{v}-\vec{v}=(s-1)\vec{v}$ is easily seen to be
$non-\vec{0}$, and so $s\vec{v}\neq \vec{v}$.
Now, apply the Lemma 3.8 to conclude that a solution set
$$\{\vec{p}+\vec{h}\,\big|\,\vec{h} \text{ solves the associated homogeneous system}\}$$
is either empty (if there is no particular solution $ \vec{p} $), or
has one element (if there is a $ \vec{p} $ and the homogeneous
system has the unique solution $\vec{0}$), or is infinite (if there
is a $ \vec{p} $ and the homogeneous system has a $non-\vec{0}$
solution, and thus by the prior paragraph has infinitely many
solutions).

Question:
The lemma shows $\vec{p}$, $\vec{h}$ being added ($\vec{p}+\vec{h}$), but the description below it the operation seems more like AND, i.e. where there is a solution (unique or infinite) ONLY if there is a particular solution.
Why is this?
Note that this is also documented in the book using the following table:


Lemma 3.8 only applies when there exists a particular solution $\vec p$. The proof of Corollary 3.11 is not correctly formulated. Instead of apply the Lemma 3.8 to conclude that a solution set
${\vec{p}+\vec{h},\big|,\vec{h} \text{ solves the associated homogeneous system}}$ is either empty[...] (which indeed makes no sense), they should just write apply the Lemma 3.8 to conclude that a solution set is either empty[...]

Ah, so $${\vec{p}+\vec{h},\big|,\vec{h} \text{ solves the associated homogeneous system}}$$ only applies when there is a particular solution?  If you would like to add your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Yes, you got it. Thank you for your tempting proposal but maybe this post won't be useful to any future reader. If you agree, it could be better to delete it.
